# How to get value from combobox in leaflet

Tags: javascript, combobox, leaflet

From 
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/936
I do :
http://jsfiddle.net/nFLc3/3/

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'topright'});
legend.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>';
    div.firstChild.onmousedown = div.firstChild.ondblclick = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    return div;
};
legend.addTo(map);

$('select').change(function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

How to get value selected value from combobox.
I try something like:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var x=document.getElementById("select");
    alert(x);
});
```

but it`s return null.

I think that this is a trivial problem, but I have a problem ..

Comment: This is a jquery problem, not a leaflet problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first code snippet just use

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

If it's too difficult for you to maintain **this** variable and you try something like in 2nd code snippet (getting value directly from element)....

As per assumption
1. your have tried to use **getElementById**
   for that you have to give your select an id

```
div.innerHTML = '<select id="mySelect"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select>';
```

and while retrieving

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var x=document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    alert(x);
});
```

2. you tried to use **select** 
   you might be trying to get value by tag name. for that you have to

   ```
   $('select').change(function(){
           var x=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
           alert(x);
       });
   ```

Note: getElementsByTagName returns an array of result, hence you have to keep the index proper if there are more than one select in the page and is difficult for maintainance. So try other options.